# AWK getline question

Tags: text-processing, awk

I making an interactive menu script just for fun with awk. I am able to receive user input and use an if statement that says if response is this then `getline<file` (I defined the variable earlier).
I used this:

```
while ((getline<file) > 0) {print};
```

However, I want to add more granularity by going furthering and adding an option for easy, medium, hard, insane which I want if a user types an easy to then getline from the file and it only print the matching items from the file.

Example: in a normal one-line I would put if I wanted to match

```
awk -F " " '/inet / {print $6}'
```

so it will only print out the item that matches `inet` .

How would I apply this principle within the `awk` script via `getline` loop?

Thanks for the help.

Basically, instead of printing out the entire file with:

```
while ((getline<file) > 0) {print};
```

I want something like this:

```
while ((getline<file) > 0) /Easy: / {print};
```

Example one-liner (preferred a similar output to this):

```
awk -F " " '/Easy: / {print $2}'
```

or just

```
awk '/Easy: / {print $0}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ( (getline < file) > 0 ) {
    if (/Easy: /) {
        print $2
    }
}
```

Make sure to read and understand everything at http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline if you're considering using getline though.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Didn't think about that. Thank you for the help!